# Dispose all non-disposed objects at once

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I am doing maintenance on a huge WPF application. There is one problem with the application it consumes large amount of memory and consumption increases with time. I searched a lot on the web but I didn't find best solution for this. There are many programs I have tried they only let me know the classes where leakage is going on but no one provide the solution to prevent it.

I have the following question for experts:

1. Can we Dispose all UnDisposed Object in a single time?.
2. What is the best way to solve this problem?.

Comment: Your "one problem" is not necessarily a problem.

Comment: I think @HenkHolterman is stating that perhaps the memory usage is a design problem or the application actually needs the memory. If it's not a design problem you need to find the resource leaks and wrap them up in using/IDisposable patterns as best you can.

Comment: No, I meant that seeing the number of MBs increase in TaskManager is not a problem by itself. There may be a problem but then @Sunny did not document it enough.

Comment: @kenny: this is much more likely to be unreleased references (particularly event handlers, in WPF) than an `IDisposable` issue.  Randomly adding `IDisposable` to a class doesn't make any difference to memory issues except in the specific case that you're using unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 1):

Any software that you use would help you identify the problem classes and **not with solutions to prevent or solve the issue.**

Well, to dispose all the objects in a single time, you would need to have a reference to the objects at that particular time. *I don't think that is practical.*

A better solution would be to identify the problem classes and resources which are not getting disposed properly and then, as Danish said, implement the **`IDisposable interface`** for them. Then, you can explicitly dispose of the objects after there use is over.

Also, you can think of using the **`'using'`** statement with those objects against disposing them, as this would reduce you pain of disposing these objects explicitly and would also result in the timely disposal.

You can read more about using the `using statement` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6564/Understanding-the-using-statement-in-C)

Answer (score -2):

You will need to check the code for those classes whose objects are memory hungry. Then, implement IDisposable interface in those classes. Next, make sure wherever the objects are created for those classes, they are disposed after use.

Simple yet incorrect, IMHO, answer to your first question will be to use static methods from GC class. But be aware that GC spawns across all the .Net applications and not just yours.

Comment: This is incorrect.  You don't implement `IDisposable` for "memory hungry" classes, you implement it for classes that contain unmanaged resources.  The `GAC` class is for enumerating the Global Assembly Cache, which is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @DanPuzey GAC was a typo and has been corrected. For IDisposable bit, I tend to disagree.

Comment: @danish: Can you explain (with references, for preference) how `IDisposable` helps with classes that do not have unmanaged resources?  My understanding is that in this case it would make no difference to the released memory, and makes no difference to the behaviour of the Garbage Collector.  I'm willing to be told that I'm wrong, but I'm pretty confident that I'm not.

Comment: @DanPuzey We cannot be sure if this is good or not in this case as we have no clue what the code does and how it does the job. When I say implement IDisposable, I refer to proper Disposable pattern. I do agree that predominantly explicit disposal should be done for unmanaged code but it is useful when you want deterministic collection. This also reduces the number of cycle GC needs to clean up. One instance where Disposable pattern is must will be when we use ODP.Net.

Comment: "that GC spawns across all the .Net applications" - not true.

Comment: @danish: "it is useful when you want deterministic collection"... Implementing `IDisposable` does *not* give you deterministic collection - it just ensures that an unreferenced object will be collected *the next time the GC runs*.  In the case of a purely-managed object, this is the case *anyway*.  ODP (Oracle Data Provider) includes an unmanaged object, and so - yes! - it benefits.  I am absolutely certain that implementing `IDisposable` for a class that *doesn't* include any unmanaged component makes *zero* difference to memory or GC resources.